# Change LeptonX theme style to Dark mode (or Light mode)

Tags: themes, abp

ABP commercial has LeptonX theme as its default theme.
There are 4 styles in LeptonX:
Light, Dark, Dim, and System.

My app has Angular UI. And the default theme style seems to be System - it changes to Light or Dark automatically when the OS settings change.

I cannot find any documentation on how to change this behaviour. I want to fix the style to Light mode always in Angular UI.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

-- app.component.ts --

```
import { ThemeService, StyleNames, lightTheme } from '@volosoft/ngx-lepton-x';

export class AppComponent {
  
  constructor(private themeService: ThemeService) {
    if (this.themeService.selectedStyle.styleName != StyleNames.Light) {
      this.themeService.setTheme(lightTheme);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YourProject.Host -> HttpApiHostModule.cs from System to Light

[image]

Comment: I am using Angular UI, and this does not work. The theme still changes when I change the OS settings.

Comment: Which ABP version do you use?

Comment: Do you want to remove the system theme? Do have cleared the cache?

Comment: ABP 7.2
You should test in Chrome Incognito window.